# Australia tax on different investment asset classes

Tags: taxes, australia

Within a single financial year, if I make $500,000 from the stock market and I purchase a rental property with that profit, am I taxed when the property is sold (in a future financial year) or is the property a different asset class and I am still obligated to pay tax on the the stock investment profit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are due to pay capital gains tax whenever you sell an asset for a profit.

If you made a profit of $500k on the sale of share you are liable to pay capital gains tax on those profits. If you then use those profits to buy another asset, whether that is more shares or a property, it has nothing to do with the capital gains event created when you sold the first shares.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, you are asking whether the $500,000 earned from the stock market can be treated as the same "asset class" as the property purchase, with the implied objective of treating the property purchase as a tax deduction against the stock market gains.

The ATO lists various [allowable deductions](https://www.ato.gov.au/Individuals/Income-and-deductions/Deductions-you-can-claim/) such as work-related expenses, gifts, superannuation and so on, with each category having its own set of rules.

Unless you can show that your expense is an allowable deduction against the income, you can’t treat the expense as a deduction against the income.

I doubt you’d be able to justify the property purchase as an allowable deduction against stock market gains, but you should consult a qualified financial advisor as there may be property-related deductions you can claim against your rental income.

In the ordinary scheme of things, the property purchase is a capital purchase but it isn't a capital gain or loss until you sell it, so it doesn't affect the tax you need to pay on your stock investment profit.

Comment: How is buying a property ever going to be an allowable deduction against the sale of shares?

Comment: @Victor I’m not an accountant, but it seems that if both were treated as [trading stock](https://www.williambuck.com/Tools/Be-Advised/Be-Advised-September-2013/Capital-gain-deemed-to-be-a-revenue-gain), there may be different considerations. In any case, the gist of my answer was that if they wanted to offset gains against expenses, the expenses must be ‘allowable deductions’ as defined by the ATO.

Comment: How is buying a property trading stock? Again, what is buying a property got anything to do with allowable deductions for profits from selling shares? The two are totally unrelated.

Comment: @Victor the link in my earlier comment gave one example. [Here’s a link to a more explicit one: property development](http://www.mondaq.com/australia/x/642948/real+estate/INCOME+TAX+IMPLICATIONS+FOR+PROPERTY+DEVELOPMENT+PROJECTS). By the time property is treated as “trading stock” (i.e. goods bought for trading) and hence on *revenue account* instead of *capital account*, it’s probably gone beyond *personal* finance and into the *commercial* finance arena, though.

Comment: @Victor As I expressed before, the principle I was pointing to was that the only expenses that can be deducted are those allowable by the ATO. I’m not trying to say that in the OP’s case, a property purchase can offset what was earned from shares. Please stop harping on a point that I’m *not* making.

Comment: But the question has nothing to do with allowable deductions, which your answer is about. It asks if the capital gain can be deferred until the property is sold. Your answer does not answer the question in anyway, you talk about something completely different that is not related to the question. It is like someone asking how to cook pasta so it is al-dente, and you provide an answer of how to probably cook a perfect stake.

Comment: @Victor I read the last part of the OP’s question as the OP’s intent being to offset sharemarket gains with a property-purchase expense. That’s what I was addressing. The sharemarket gain would be irrelevant to the question otherwise.

Comment: The OP is clearly talking about the possibility of deferring capital gains tax (which is usually only allowed on certain special events), and at no time mentions anything about deductions?????

Comment: @Victor The stock market profit is mentioned twice, at the start and end of the question, both times linked to the property purchase. There's very little else in the question. The OP and at least 2 others have agreed with your interpretation. I've edited to clarify how I saw the question, and I'm willing to leave it at that. I agree with the conclusions drawn from your interpretation and have up-voted your answer, but let's agree to disagree on our interpretations of the question as presented.